# Need to update the users table password field on codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, sql-update

# table name is users#

## model name is user_model##

### controller name is get_password ###

issue - no change on the password , remain as old

```
> model(user_model)



 public function updatePassword($email,$data)

 {   
      $data1=array('password'=>$data);

      $this->db->where('email','$email');

      $this->db->update('users','password'); 

    $success = $this->db->affected_rows(); 

    if(!$success){
        error_log('Unable to updatePassword');
        return false;
    }        
    return true;
} 


 > controller(get_password)

public function index($rs=FALSE)
{
$this->load->database();
$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->load->model('user_model');
$this->load->library('session');

  $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'password Confirmation', 'required|matches[password]');

 if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
  {
              echo form_open();
              $this->load->view('users/fpre');
 }
else
 {


  $data = array(
        'password' => md5($this->input->post('password')),


  );

    $email =array(

        'email' =>$this->input->post('email')
  );



   $this->user_model->updatePassword($data,$email);

  echo "Congratulations!";
  }

}
```

it shows no error but the password is not updated remain same at users table..i can't find the problem is, please help me to find it out ..

Comment: Don't use MD5 for passwords it can get hacked you should use php password hash http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php password column on db varchar 255 and to verify http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Controller** (get_password):

```
public function index() {
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library(array('form_validation', 'session'));
        $this->load->model('user_model');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Current password', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('newpassword', 'password', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('newpassconf', 'password Confirmation', 'required|matches[newpassword]');

        $email = $this->input->post('email');

        $success = false;
        $msg = '';

        if ($this->form_validation->run() !== FALSE) {
            $password = md5($this->input->post('password'));

            if ($this->user_model->checkPassword($email, $password)){
                $newpassword = md5($this->input->post('newpassword'));

                if ($this->user_model->updatePassword($email, $newpassword)){
                    $success = true;                    
                }else{
                    $msg = 'Unable to updatePassword';
                }               
            }else{
                $msg = 'Incorrect password';
            }
        }   

        if ($success){
            echo 'Congratulations!';        
        }else{          
            $this->load->view('users/fpre', array(
                'email'=>$email,
                'msg'=>$msg
            )); 
        }
    }
```

**Model** (user_model):

```
public function checkPassword($email, $password) {
    $users = $this->db->get_where('users', array('email'=>$email))->row();

    return $users->password === $password;
}

public function updatePassword($email, $newpassword) {      
    $data = array('password' => $newpassword);

    $this->db->where('email', $email)
    ->update('users', $data);

    $success = $this->db->affected_rows();  

    if (!$success) {
        error_log('Unable to updatePassword');
    }   

    return $success;
}
```

**View** (users/fpre):

```
if ($msg){
    echo 'Message: '.$msg;  
}

echo form_open();
echo form_input('email', $email);
echo form_password('password');
echo form_password('newpassword');
echo form_password('newpassconf');
echo form_submit('', 'Enviar');
echo form_close();
```

Changes to compare:
[image][image]

Comment: thanks for you help..it's working...Can we update the current password with out enter the email and current password ??

Comment: Yes, you will need implement a login into your project using CodeIgniter Session Library (https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your model function shows the parameters are expected to be email and then password, but your controller is passing them through be other way around.

```
$this->user_model->updatePassword($data,$email);
```

Should be:

```
$this->user_model->updatePassword($email,$data);
```

I also believe the data needs to be passed differently. The where() function expects either `where(field_name, value)` or `where(array(field_name => value))`. Looking at your code, you seem to be mixing both of those.

Using set() should help with this too, so instead of

```
$data1=array('password'=>$data);
$this->db->where('email','$email');
$this->db->update('users','password');
```

Use:

```
$this->db->set($data);
$this->db->where($email);
$this->db->update('users');
```

*Note: code untested.*

Answer (score 0):

I believe this line `$this->db->update('users','password');` should be `$this->db->update('users', $data);`.

Right now you are not passing the password to the update function. You are passing the string "password".

Comment: no..i tried but still no change on the table users. password remain old.

Comment: As Parker1090 said, you also have your parameters backwards when you call the updatePassword function.